# Access Asp.net MVC web Api In Android

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

Would i have to publish my Asp.net MVC 4 web api to internet in order to access it in my Android application using JSONParser ... or will it work well  if i will  publish it locally on IIS ?

Please advise !!

Comment: please publish if you wants to access it on devices.

Comment: or you can use it locally for development purpose,both options are available to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will function just as well with the Internet or the Local Network. What you will choose will depend on how you want your users to access the API service. If they are going to access it remotely then it will make sense to publish it on the Internet. But if they are only suppose to access it internally then you can set it up locally.